# Nested groups do not maintain absolute position

Tags: kineticjs

I have found a few issues around nested groups.

Starting with a bit of code.  I have tried this code against both v4.2.0 and 4.3.1 of the kinetic libraries.  Each version gives me different behavior, but neither is correct so I will describe both.  Here is the code:

```
<script>

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "container",
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 1000,
            height: 800
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);

        var grp1 = new Kinetic.Group(
        {
            id: 'grp1',
            name: 'grp1',
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            draggable: true
        });
        grp1.setAbsolutePosition(100, 100);

        var sqr1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fill: '#FFFFFF',
            stroke: '#000000',
            strokeWidth: .4,
            id: 'sqr1',
            name: 'sqr1'
        });
        grp1.add(sqr1);

        var grp2 = new Kinetic.Group(
        {
            id: 'grp2',
            name: 'grp2',
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            draggable: true
        });
        grp2.setAbsolutePosition(110, 110);

        var sqr2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 110,
            y: 110,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            fill: '#FFFFFF',
            stroke: '#00FF00',
            strokeWidth: .4,
            id: 'sqr2',
            name: 'sqr2'
        });

        grp2.add(sqr2);
        grp1.add(grp2);

        layer.add(grp1);

        grp2.on('click', function (evt) {
            var pos = grp2.getAbsolutePosition();
            alert(pos.x + ', ' + pos.y);
        });

        layer.draw();
</script>
```

If you run this against v4.2.0 you will see that grp2 is placed not at 110, 110 in relation to the stage, but at 210, 210 with relation to the stage (click on the green square to see it's position).  I tried removing the setAbsolutePosition calls and then it will draw the groups correctly, however if you drag the groups around and then click on the green square again you will see that the position is now relative to the initial position of the nested group, not the stage.

If you run the above code against v4.3.1 you will see that the second group is again placed at 210, 210 relative to the stage.  If you attempt to click on the green square under this version, the position will be shown and then the sqaure will disappear completely with no javascript errors thrown.  I have a lot of code that uses nested groups and this happens everywhere when I try to upgrade to 4.3.1 - things disappear when I click on them if the groups are nested.  I have tried this in IE9 and Firefox with the same results.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the correct absolute position for the nested group?

Comment: can you put some working code in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tbYLe/2/

You have to add an extra attribute to your groups 'dragOnTop' (use with 4.3.1)

```
    var grp1 = new Kinetic.Group(
    {
        id: 'grp1',
        name: 'grp1',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        draggable: true,
        dragOnTop: false   //<-- right here is what you need, add this to your other group too
    });
```

This prevents the element from being placed in a new layer while dragging and will fix your disappearing square issue.

Regarding Absolute Position:

You need to set the absolute position after you have nested your groups, not after creating them. Take a look:

```
    grp1.add(sqr1);
    grp2.add(sqr2);

    grp1.add(grp2);                      //nested groups

    grp1.setAbsolutePosition(100, 100);  //set absolute position after nesting groups
    grp2.setAbsolutePosition(110, 110);  //set absolute position after nesting groups

    layer.add(grp1);
```